# One android app to control another app

Tags: android

I currently have an android app in the market which has a free and pro version of the app. The pro app doesn't provide any functionality it is just an unlock app which enables extra features from within the pro app.

What I want to be able to is to allow the user from the free app to enable SMS messaging that when a certain message arrives it wipes the content of the free app. However, I do not want to enable the SMS permission on the free as this may put people off as it is a password app, so what I want to do is the following:

1. The user, from the free app enables the sms check
2. The pro app has permission to check SMS messages and if the app settings from the free app enables this sms check, then the pro app checks for when a message arrives with particular criteria
3. If the pro app finds the matching critera, then the pro triggers the free app to remove all content of the app, i.e. all data within the apps preferences and database.

Is this possible and if so how could it be done, couldn't find anything on Google, probably using the incorrect keywords!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Intents and broadcast receives to communicate between the apps.